# specific gridview data to be moved into excel file

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I am trying to move the specific gridview data into the excel file but I am getting an error as `object reference not set to the instance of an object`

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" Font-Names = "Arial"
Font-Size = "11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C2D69B" 
HeaderStyle-BackColor = "green">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<HeaderTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="Chckcol0" runat="server" Checked="true"/>
<asp:Label ID="lbl_catid" runat="server" Text=" CategoryID"></asp:Label>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lbl_catid" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cat_id")%>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
<HeaderTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="Chckcol1" runat="server" Checked="true"/>
<asp:Label ID="lbl_catname" runat="server" Text="category Name"></asp:Label>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lbl_categoryname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("categoryname")%>'>     </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
<HeaderTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="Chckcol2" runat="server" Checked="true"/>
<asp:Label ID="description" runat="server" Text="description"></asp:Label>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lbl_description" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("description")%>'>  </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And my code behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Database=mylibrary_db;User ID=root;Password=MyLuck2010");
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        fillgrid();
    }
}
protected void fillgrid()
{
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("select cat_id,categoryname,description from library_category", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
protected void getcheckedgridview()
{
    CheckBox chkCol0 = (CheckBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("chkCol0");
    CheckBox chkCol1 = (CheckBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("chkCol1");
    CheckBox chkCol2 = (CheckBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("chkCol2");
    ArrayList arr;
    if (ViewState["States"] == null)
    {
        arr = new ArrayList();
    }
    else
    {
        arr = (ArrayList)ViewState["States"];
    }
    arr.Add(chkCol0.Checked);
    arr.Add(chkCol1.Checked);
    arr.Add(chkCol2.Checked);
    ViewState["States"] = arr;
}
protected void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
    ArrayList arr = (ArrayList)ViewState["States"];
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(arr[0]);
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(arr[1]);
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(arr[2]);
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("chkCol0").Visible = false;
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].FindControl("chkCol1").Visible = false;
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[2].FindControl("chkCol2").Visible = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
        row.Cells[0].Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(arr[0]);
        row.Cells[1].Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(arr[1]);
        row.Cells[2].Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(arr[2]);
        row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");

        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            row.Cells[0].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
            row.Cells[1].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
            row.Cells[2].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
        }

    }

    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
    string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
    Response.Write(style);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

}

Comment: i am just getting an error as object reference not set to the instance of an object when i am clicking on a button

Comment: i am getting an error in this line as object ref not set           GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(arr[0]);which is under the button click event

Answer (score 0):

The fault is most likely to be with the `Convert.ToBoolean(arr[0]);` (see the line `GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(arr[0]);)`

I would put a break tag on the faulting line and see what the value of `arr[0]` is. I would guess arr is empty or null and your ViewState is not returning the data you are expecting. This maybe because your method `getcheckedgridview()` is not called by your code (or at least, not by the code you've displayed)!

You could try (where the only change is the first line of the method)

```
protected void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getcheckedgridview();//Only change to your code
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Style.Add("background-color", "green");
    ArrayList arr = (ArrayList)ViewState["States"];
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(arr[0]);
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(arr[1]);
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(arr[2]);
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("chkCol0").Visible = false;
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].FindControl("chkCol1").Visible = false;
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[2].FindControl("chkCol2").Visible = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
        row.Cells[0].Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(arr[0]);
        row.Cells[1].Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(arr[1]);
        row.Cells[2].Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(arr[2]);
        row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");

        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            row.Cells[0].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
            row.Cells[1].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
            row.Cells[2].Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B");
        }

    }

    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
    string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
    Response.Write(style);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

**Edit**

Based upon your comments, I think the error message is now due to your code not finding the control in question. So

```
CheckBox chkCol0 = (CheckBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("chkCol0");
```

does not find the control called *"chkCol0"* and so therefore chkCol0 is null.

Comment: @Ashish - do what? I've added the code for you now with an explanation of what I think is going on.

Comment: now i am getting same error in  arr.Add(chkCol0.Checked); line as the code is under getcheckedgridview method

Comment: Sorry Dave still i am getting the same error after updating the code

Comment: it is showing as object reference not set to the instance of an object

Comment: now excel file is getting generated but data of gridview is not getting bindup in excel file

Comment: @Ashish That's a different question then. I'd mark this as answer/helpful (or not) and create a new question, posting your new code as I'm sure you've made updates.